# Convert a date to intervals of time

Tags: r

I have a column in my `data.frame` that is formatted as date (`"2006-03-09 17:00:00"`) and I want a new column that gives me ranges like "morning", "afternoon", "evening". I am trying the following without success:

```
mydf <- mydf %>%
        mutate (dateInterval = ifelse (data < "13:00", "morning",
                               ifelse (data > "18:00", "evening", "afternoon")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shared your data so it is difficult to produce an ad-hoc solution.

The steps are the following:
1) Be sure that your date is in `POSIXct` class

```
mydf$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(mydf$timestamp, mydf$timestamp), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

2) Extract the Hour component from this Date&Time object

```
mydf$hour <- format(strptime(as.character(mydf$timestamp), "%H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")
```

3) Create a table containing the `time_slot` information

```
description <- c("Morning", "Day", "Evening", "Night")
from <- as.character(c("07:00:00", "10:30:00", "17:30:00", "20:30:00"))  
to <- as.character(c("10:29:59", "17:29:59", "20:29:59", "06:59:59"))  
context_table <- data.frame(description, from, to)
```

4) Be sure that `context_table$from` and `context_table$to` are `character` type in order to allow comparison with `mydf$hour`

```
context_table$from <- as.character(context_table$from)
context_table$to <- as.character(context_table$to)
```

5) Associate the `context_table$description` to each record in `mydf`

```
mydf$time_slot <- NULL
for (i in 1:(dim(context_table)[1]-1)){
        mydf[mydf$hour_crash >= context_table$from[i] & mydf$hour_crash <= context_table$to[i], "time_slot"] <- context_table[i, "description"]
}
mydf[is.na(mydf$time_slot), "time_slot"] <- context_table[dim(context_table), "description"]
```

Since the clock is circular in the interval [00:00:00; 23:59:59], it is necessary to do the workaround of point 5).

Answer (score 2):

```
## Building your datetime data
datetime <- c("2006-03-09 17:00:00", "2006-03-09 19:00:00", "2006-03-09 10:00:00", "2006-03-09 22:00:00")

hour <- as.integer(substr(datetime, 12, 13))
df <- data.frame(datetime=datetime, hour=hour, dateInterval=cut(hour, c(0, 7, 10, 12, 18, 24), labels=c("night", "morning", "noon", "afternoon", "evening")))

df
#             datetime   hour  dateInterval
#1 2006-03-09 17:00:00    17      afternoon
#2 2006-03-09 19:00:00    19        evening
#3 2006-03-09 10:00:00    10        morning
#4 2006-03-09 22:00:00    22        evening
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.  Can you better explain the ratio behind cut and especially why you used -Inf and + Inf?  Can you also improve your solution by considering also half hour like afternoon start at 16:30 and end and 18:29?

Comment: You could also do cuts like this: `dateInterval=cut(hour, c(0, 7, 10, 12, 18, 24)`. -Inf and +Inf is just to handle greater positive number for evening and negative number for midnight. It could be confusing. So, I updated my cut.

Comment: and what about handling cut considering also the minutes? Thank you very much for explaining because I just started R and it is so useful learning from your answer

Comment: To include minutes, you would need to extract minutes with hours: `substr(datetime, 12, 16)` and then convert this to numeric using `gsub` (as you would need to replace : with .). Later update cuts such as `c(0, 7, 10, 16.30, 18.30, 24)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for replacing my very long and messy code with just 1 line ;)